# Advanced Mongoose Aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, lookup

So what I currently have is working. But what I want in addition is, that I get in the same query the matched data from Collection C with the currently logged in user.

So the point is the following: A user can have multiple CollectionA's. And users can join the CollectionA, which is specified in CollectionB.
In the aggregation I get every joined user. But what I want in addition is, that I can see the currently logged in users data from Collection B.

```
CollectionA.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "collectionB",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "col_a_id",
        as: "colB",
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "colB.user_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(
          request.user.id
        ),
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "collectionB",
        let: { id: "$_id" },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: { $eq: ["$$id", "$col_a_id"] },
            },
          },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "user",
              localField: "user_id",
              foreignField: "_id",
              as: "user",
            },
          },
          {
            $addFields: {
              x: { $arrayElemAt: ["$x", 0] },
            },
          },
          {
            $project: {
              param1: "$x.a",
              param2: "$x.b",
            },
          },
        ],
        as: "completeList",
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        param: 1,
        completeList: "$completeList",
      },
    },
  ]);
```

```
Collection A: 

_id: 11
param: "fff"


Collection B:
_id: 543
col_a_id: 11,
user_id: 789,
param_I_want: "only from the user who is logged in"


User:

_id: 789
param1: "trfewe",
param2: "fewfew"
```

So my current output is like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "11",
        "param": "fff",
        "completeList": [
            {
                "_id": "222",
                "user_id": 789,
                "col_a_id": 11,
                "param1": "trfewe",
                "param2": "fewfew",
            },
            {
                "_id": "333",
                "user_id": 899,
                "col_a_id": 11,
                "param1": "fwfer",
                "param2": "gerwa",
            },
        ]
    }
...
]
```

And what I want is this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "11",
        "param": "fff",
        "completeList": [
            {
                "_id": "222",
                "user_id": 789,
                "col_a_id": 11,
                "param1": "trfewe",
                "param2": "fewfew",
            },
            {
                "_id": "333",
                "user_id": 899,
                "col_a_id": 11,
                "param1": "fwfer",
                "param2": "gerwa",
            },
        ],
        "param_I_want": "only from the user who is logged in"
    }
...
]
```

And since I'm asking a question I add another one into it: In the aggregation I use the same lookup. The second one is in a pipeline.
Is there a way to do it in a better way? I mean if I imagine it being used by thousands of people, could there be performance issues?
If yes why and how can I improve it?

Comment: can you give the sample date before the query? what data produced this output?So we understand and test it also.

Comment: Hey I just edited my question. You can see it now